# How to declare intent,class,buttons in one loop?

Tags: android

Why this doesn't work?

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity {

 Button[] b = null;
 Intent[] intent=null;
 Class[] klasa;
 Typeface font;
 TextView glavninaslov;
 ImageView plavi,ljubicasti;
 AnimationDrawable plavian,ljubicastian;
 String[] naslovi;
 int i=0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    String[] naslovi = {"","First","Second","Third","Fourth","Fifth"};
    font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"FatMarker.ttf");
    b = new Button[]
            {
            ( Button ) findViewById(R.id.button1),
            ( Button ) findViewById(R.id.button2),
            ( Button ) findViewById(R.id.button3),
            ( Button ) findViewById(R.id.button4),
            ( Button ) findViewById(R.id.button5),
            };

    for(i=1;i<6;i++)
    {   
        klasa[i]=Class.forName(naslovi[i]);//Problem is in:"Class not found exception"
        intent[i] = new Intent(MainActivity.this,klasa[i]);
        b[i].setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {  
            public void onClick(View v)
                {
                startActivity(intent[i]);
                gasenje();
                }
             });
    }
```

Can anyone help me...?
Does anyone had similar problems?
Please help me... 
The rest of code cannot affect on program... Please help me... I would appreciate it...

I have updated my code...it starts mainactivity but when i click on some button it crush app...
    Button[] b = null;
    Intent[] intent=null;
    Typeface font;
    TextView glavninaslov;
    ImageView plavi,ljubicasti;
    AnimationDrawable plavian,ljubicastian;

```
int i=0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Class[] naslovi = {
            First.class,
            Second.class,
            Third.class,
            Fourth.class,
            Fifth.class};

    font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"FatMarker.ttf");
    b = new Button[]
            {
            ( Button ) findViewById(R.id.button1),
            ( Button ) findViewById(R.id.button2),
            ( Button ) findViewById(R.id.button3),
            ( Button ) findViewById(R.id.button4),
            ( Button ) findViewById(R.id.button5),
            };
    intent = new Intent[b.length];
    for(i=0;i<5;i++)
    {   

        intent[i] = new Intent(MainActivity.this,naslovi[i]);
        b[i].setTag(i);
        b[i].setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {  
            public void onClick(View v)
                {
                startActivity(intent[(Integer)v.getTag()]);
                gasenje();
                }
             });
    }
```

This code works...thanks guys

Comment: do you have calsses called "First", "Second" etc?

Comment: yes....................

Comment: Are they all classes in manifest?

Comment: Make sure they are in the same package as the MainActivity

Comment: yes..........................

Comment: Post more about whats going wrong.... console output; behavior decsription; anything.

Comment: Have you tried using fully qualified name of the desired class, the same one that getName() would return, not only class name?

Answer (score 2):

#### Update:

Rather than using reflection as you are to create these classes, as kcoppock suggested you should just do this:

```
Class[] naslovi = {
            First.class,
            Second.class,
            Third.class,
            Fourth.class,
            Fifth.class};
```

And then in your loop:

```
intent[i] = new Intent(MainActivity.this, naslovi[i]);
```

#### Original Answer:

Assuming you have a classes called `First`, `Second`, etc, you need to include the package name:

```
String[] naslovi = {"",
                     "com.package.First",
                     "com.package.Second",
                     "com.package.Third",
                     "com.package.Fourth",
                     "com.package.Fifth"};
```

Replace `com.package` with the package for each class.

Also after you fix that, I foresee that you'll then get an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` - remove the blank "" element from `naslovi`, and change your `for` loop to `for(i=0;i<5;i++)`

Comment: Also, it doesn't appear there's any reason to do this in the first place -- just make `klasa` an array of `Class`: `Class<? extends Activity> klasa = new Class<? extends Activity>[] { First.class, Second.class };`

Comment: intent[i] = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Class.forName(naslovi[i]));
thats the problem

Comment: I think whats suggested by @kcoppock is the better solution. +1

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `i` will not be retained at the current value when the `OnClickListener` is executed. You can use the buttons' tag value to retain the proper value.

```
for (int i=0; i<b.length; i++) {
    //existing logic
    b[i].setTag(i);
    b[i].setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            startActivity(intent[(Integer)view.getTag()]);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: True. You can also create a final variable outside the listener and set it's value to `i`.

Comment: I commented on your post. You are missing the initialization of your intents array.